# adding drag events using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, drag

I am using jQuery to add dragStart events to a button.

Here is my html:

```js
$('.btn-photo').on('dragstart', function (event) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SinglePhoto" class="btn-section btn-photo" draggable="true"></div>
```

This works in Chrome but not Safari. Does anyone know why?

In Safari, I can drag the element but it does not show it as being dragged. 
In Chrome, I can drag the element and I see it being dragged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: That's browser implementation... Obviously Chrome is better than Safari and has more support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is  100% the right way to do it, but you could try setting the drag image using setDragImage on the dataTransfer property of the event:

```
$('.btn-photo').on('dragstart', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let img = $(this)[0];
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
});
```

I've also thrown an `event.preventDefault()` in there just in case it has something to do with that (I'm not on Safari so can't test).

[Reference](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html)